# Android app is been rejected from Google because of Permissions & Location Permissions policies

Tags: android

My app has been rejected from google and here is what they said :

**We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to location in the background, however  your permission declaration form did not reflect this. Please log in to your Play Console to resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background.**

My app is not using background location :
here is my permissions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwTHi.png)

Comment: Does your app use location and if yes then where(activities,services where list them ) ?

Comment: @aryanagarwal it has only google map. it does not have service for location

Comment: `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` , try searching this in your app folder and see if it is present , I read this https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/535

Comment: @aryanagarwal i don't have this permission im my project

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/535 mentions that u can use this to solve `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>` , maybe this can help u